# htaccess Rewrite (remove php extension)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

today I have a problem with my .htaccess file. On my server I have several folders, each of folders is separately website example below:

Server structure (global folder)

```
- my_portfolio
- website_two
- my_website
- example
```

In "example" folder I have that .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

#To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

RewriteRule working good when I open my website address is without "www" and .php extensions is invisible, but when I click on a link to other website in menu I get something like this:
www.example.com/example/contact.

Address to my website is www.example.com and everything for this website is inside example folder on a server. I dont know where or what I wrote wrong. Always when I try to go on to another webside rewrite engine give me a link without .php extension but add to folder name before link.

This is good example:

```
www.example.com/contact.php - normal link without htaccess
example.com/example(folder name where is a website)/contact - now
example.com/contact - should be
```

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your rules and keep redirect rules before internal routing rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Also test this from a new browser to avoid old 301 cache.

Comment: Hello anubhava thanks for your answear but effect is this same I check this on a new browser I download firefox for that, still folder name is past in link I don't know why

Comment: Is `/example/` not set as `DocumentRoot` in your `VirtualHost` setup?

Comment: I have hosting from provider this is not my localhost or my server. My catalog on a server look that: /public_html/webisteone/index.php
I don't have a access to VirtualHost settings only what I can do is a write correct code inside htaccess and put this file to "websiteone" catalog. All my settings in htaccess I wrote above.